# Is it possible to chain .all() instead of using Promise.all()?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I'm working in Node.js with bluebird promises. I wanted to use Promise.all in my chain of promises, and tried this :

```js
request-promise(some_API_call)
.then( (responseBody) => {
      
      // using responseBody to determine N new API calls to make
  
      var arrayPromises = [];
  
      for (var i=0 ; i<N ; i++) {
            var newPromise = request-promise(new_API_call_i);
            arrayPromises.push(newPromise);
      } 
  
      return(arrayPromises);
 
})
.all(arrayPromises)
.then( (arrayResults) => {
    // do something
});
```

Throws me an error : `arrayPromises is undefined`.

The only other way I can think of is :

```js
request-promise(some_API_call)
.then( (responseBody) => {
      
      // using responseBody to determine N new API calls to make
  
      var arrayPromises = [];
  
      for (var i=0 ; i<N ; i++) {
            var newPromise = request-promise(new_API_call_i);
            arrayPromises.push(newPromise);
      } 

      Promise.all(arrayPromises)
      .then( (arrayResults) => {
          // do something
      });
})
```

I wonder if :

- Any of these patterns is correct ?
- I'm not falling again and again in another anti-pattern : is it correct to nest promise chains in this context ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`arrayPromises` is undefined because it is defined within a callback scope that the following `then` doesn't have access to. I think you would want to return `Promise.all` from your initial `then` and continue the chain from there:

```
request-promise(some_API_call)
.then( (responseBody) => {

      // using responseBody to determine N new API calls to make

      var arrayPromises = [];

      for (var i=0 ; i<N ; i++) {
            var newPromise = request-promise(new_API_call_i);
            arrayPromises.push(newPromise);
      } 

      return Promise.all(arrayPromises);

})
.then( (arrayResults) => {
    // do something
});
```

Comment: Lovely. Both of my ideas at the same time written simply, while keeping the code flat. Why couldn't I imagine that in the first place T_T. Thanks !

Comment: Solutions to other people's problems are always much more clear to me than solutions to my own problems :P Glad it helped!